# Cannot get NextJS Image component to properly transition height

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I have a page on which when the user scrolls down, the headerbar changes size (goes from 120px to 70px). I added this transition as a swap between Tailwind classes, and added a height transition, which works well. I'm now trying to get the site logo, which is in the header, to resize with it. I tried using the NextJS Image component, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
export default function Header() {
    const baseClasses = classNames(
        "transition-[height] border-b border-b-black fixed top-0 left-0 w-full z-[100] bg-header-gray flex justify-center shadow-[0_1px_20px_1px_#777] px-4 py-2"
    );
    const imgClasses = classNames("transition-[height]");
    const stdClasses = `${baseClasses} h-[70px]`,
        fullClasses = `${baseClasses} h-[120px]`,
        stdImageHeight = 53,
        fullImageHeight = 100;

    const pathname = usePathname();
    const [classes, setClasses] = useState<string>(
        pathname !== "/" ? stdClasses : fullClasses
    );
    const [imgHeight, setImgHeight] = useState<number>(
        pathname !== "/" ? stdImageHeight : fullImageHeight
    );

    const updateClasses = () => {
        if (window.scrollY <= 50) {
            setClasses(fullClasses);
            setImgHeight(fullImageHeight);
        } else {
            setClasses(stdClasses);
            setImgHeight(stdImageHeight);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (pathname === "/") {
            updateClasses();
            document.addEventListener("scroll", updateClasses);
        } else {
            setClasses(stdClasses);
            document.removeEventListener("scroll", updateClasses);
        }
    }, [pathname]);

    return (
        <header id="site_header" className={classes}>
            <div className="w-full max-w-screen-xl">
                <div className={`h-[${imgHeight}px] relative`}>
                    <Image
                        className={imgClasses}
                        src={gp_logo}
                        alt="Gamers' Plane Logo"
                        fill={true}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
}
```

I've tried setting `imgHeight` to the style and as a Tailwind class (`h-[${imgHeight}px]`). I also tried giving the Image `fill={true}` with a div parent, but because the div parent takes up the full width of the page, it squashes. I also tried `width: fit-content` on the div, but because the image is the content, it stays full size.

I'd like to have the image calculate its own respective height/width based on the space available to it. Can I do this with the Image component, or should I go back to the img tag?

Comment: Can you post the component where you are using the Image?

Comment: @L.Nelson I've added the full component in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a Tailwinds issue. Tailwinds can't interpolate custom classnames using template literals at run time. You are doing `h-[${imgHeight}px]`.

If you just change your variables for the height for the full tailwind class and use those in your div, everything should work. I got it to locally.

```
const  stdImageHeight = "h-[53px]",
        fullImageHeight = "h-[100px]";


<div className={`${imgHeight} relative`}>
```

Once you've adjusted your custom classes, there are a few ways to achieve your sizing issues. Traditionally, we would set the Width, instead of the Height as it. What I would suggest is something like this.

```
<div className="w-full max-w-screen-xl">
 <div className={`${imgWidth} relative`}>
  <Image 
     className={imgClasses}                   
     src="https://placekitten.com/200/100"
     alt="Gamers' Plane Logo"
     width={200}
     height={100}
   />
 </div>
</div>
```

Instead of using fill, it defines the larger size of the image and has a changing width. Be sure to keep `relative`. This should scale nicely.

Alternatively if you want to use fill, you can just set a imgHeight and imgWidth using your current process.

```
<div className="w-full max-w-screen-xl">
  <div className={`${imgWidth} ${imgHeight} relative`}>
   <Image
     className={imgClasses}
     src="https://placekitten.com/400/200"
     alt="Gamers' Plane Logo"
     fill={true}
   />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, this is one of the things I tried, but as the image is at a 2:1 width:height ratio, the image just squishes across the entire screen; it doesn't maintain it's ratio.

Comment: That seems obvious no? Just add a width property as well as a height so they scale correctly. I assumed you were using an SVG because its a logo. SVG's scale just fine without this width property but pixel images require a ratio.  You have to use custom classes in tailwinds like I mentioned above, its not something to try, its the only way.

Comment: Also, when I was using your code, I noticed that you are calling window to set initital State. This is likely going to cause issues since Next tries to prerender. You should setState using window with a useEffect on mount, so that window is available.

Comment: Thanks for the note about SVG. It's not obvious, because I'm a BE learning FE things, heh, I had no idea that SVG would scale while pixel wouldn't. And as it's a client component, given the use of state, pre-rendering isn't an issue.